# Oracle trigger with select inside that returns multiple results

Tags: sql, oracle, select, triggers

I have the trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTERE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
  V_PROJECT_ID VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  SELECT PJ_ID INTO V_PROJECT_ID FROM PROJECT_ROLES_GROUPS
  WHERE GRP_ID = :OLD.GRP_ID;

  UPDATE PROJECTS SET TOCUHED = 1 WHERE ID = V_PROJECT_ID;
END;
```

but the select statement inside the trigger returns multiple values.

How should I handle this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `in` for the query instead of a variable?

```
BEGIN
  UPDATE PROJECTS
      SET TOUCHED = 1
      WHERE ID IN (SELECT PJ_ID 
                   FROM PROJECT_ROLES_GROUPS
                   WHERE GRP_ID = :NEW.GRP_ID
                  );
END
```

Comment: notice for readers: I had to change :OLD to :NEW for the trigger to work when inserting which makes sense :)